# How to run Android Studio 2.3 completely offline?

Tags: android, android-studio, offline

I want to run Android Studio 2.3 (latest) Offline but can't do so ?
error -gradle sync etc

Comment: make Gradle offline from setting

Comment: not working ,creating an error,gradle sync failed

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the "Offline work" checkbox in the Preferences window:

AndroidStudio -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> Offline work.

Please note that you have to download your dependencies the first time before you can work offline.